# What does 'question items' means?

Tags: meaning

This is the sentence

"True or false question items and short answer ones were also analyzed separately. "

I do not know what 'question items' mean

Full sentence:

"The data have revealed that the candidates performed in computer-based reading as well as in paper-based reading. To be more specific, True or false question items and short answer ones were also analysed separately."

Comment: Could you clarify what you're asking please?

Comment: Please do not ask 2 identical questions

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about very basic language and better suited to [ell.se]

Answer (score 1):

It just means *questions*. The sentence:

> *True or false questions and short answer ones were also analysed separately.*

makes just as much sense.

Comment: True-or-false questions and short-answer questions were also analyzed separately.

Comment: @Jim I was thinking the same thing, although I'd go a little further: True-or-false and short-answer questions were also analyzed separately.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by *items* it is referring to the various ways a multiple choice question (to include a true/false question) can be asked within a questionnaire. Isn't it?

From a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_choice):

> The items of a multiple choice test are often colloquially referred to as "questions," but this is a misnomer because many items are not phrased as questions. For example, they can be presented as incomplete statements, analogies, or mathematical equations. **Thus, the more general term "item" is a more appropriate label**.

Comment: This is a good observation, but it doesn't quite make sense in context. There's nothing to analyze in the choices to a true/false question. Also, “items” is also the antecedent of “short answer ones,” which do not have multiple choices.